# Why does copying a file line by line greatly affect copy speed in Python?

Tags: python, file

A while ago, I made a Python script which looked similar to this:

```
with open("somefile.txt", "r") as f, open("otherfile.txt", "a") as w:
    for line in f:
        w.write(line)
```

Which, of course, worked pretty slowly on a `100mb` file.

However, I changed the program to do this

```
ls = []
with open("somefile.txt", "r") as f, open("otherfile.txt", "a") as w:
    for line in f:
        ls.append(line)
        if len(ls) == 100000:
            w.writelines(ls)
            del ls[:]
```

And the file copied much faster. My question is, why does the second method work faster even though the program copies the same number of lines (albeit collects them and prints them one by one)?

Comment: This is interesting. I think it may have something to do with the IO operations. `writelines` might join the list of strings with newlines and write them all at once. I doubt that `writelines` calls `write` for every element in the list/generator. I would assume that the speed increase comes from the implmentation in C.

Comment: Fewer hard drive head seeks between reading and writing?

Comment: did you try `w.writelines(f)`? I also presume r should be f

Comment: What if you replaced `w.writelines(ls)` with `w.write("\n".join(ls))`? How does the speed compare to your existing cases?

Comment: Your logic is also slightly flawed as you only write when `len(ls) == 100000:` so potentially you write less lines to one file, also  `open("otherfile.txt", "w",buffering=1000) as w:` beats writelines for me

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: I have Python 3.4.3, but the effect is similar on all versions. And @Kevin, This was actually just something I noticed; I do not have the 100mb file anymore, but if you know where I can get one, I can test it

Comment: If you literally just want to copy a file quickly, then use `shutil.copy`.

Comment: I was a noob at the time I wrote this (a year or a year and a half ago), but I answered a question of someone asking how to do it, and I remembered coming across this

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry, edited. That would make the program pretty uncooperative, thanks

Comment: Do you see what Padraic is saying about your source? If you have 19999 lines, it would only write 10000 of them to the new file.

Comment: No, there is a generator running over the lines and it will keep going until the lines are done. I tested this myself and looked at the filesize

Comment: `del ls[:]` deletes it's contents, not the variable. Also, it does not break out of the for loop

Comment: He was saying that I had an error by using `r` instead of `f`

Comment: For the file variable

Comment: It doesn't appear to be writing them, only adding them to `ls`

Comment: It writes to the file once `100000` lines are reached. I am just recreating old code I used a while ago, I can make it perfect if you want so it copies the remaining lines (which of course, I did when I used it back then) but laziness kicks in

Comment: For example, this may not copy the last `4000` lines or something because I have `One mil and 4000`

Answer (score 2):

I may have found a reason why `write` is slower than `writelines`. In looking through the CPython source (3.4.3) I found the code for the `write` function (took out irrelevent parts).

`Modules/_io/fileio.c`

```
static PyObject *
fileio_write(fileio *self, PyObject *args)
{
    Py_buffer pbuf;
    Py_ssize_t n, len;
    int err;
    ...
    n = write(self->fd, pbuf.buf, len);
    ...

    PyBuffer_Release(&pbuf);

    if (n < 0) {
        if (err == EAGAIN)
            Py_RETURN_NONE;
        errno = err;
        PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_IOError);
        return NULL;
    }

    return PyLong_FromSsize_t(n);
}
```

If you notice, this function actually **returns a value**, the size of the string that has been written, which is **another function call**.

I tested this out to see if it actually had a return value, and it did.

```
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
    x = f.write("hello")
    print(x)

>>> 5
```

The following is the code for the `writelines` function implementation in CPython (took out irrelevent parts).

`Modules/_io/iobase.c`

```
static PyObject *
iobase_writelines(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *lines, *iter, *res;

    ...

    while (1) {
        PyObject *line = PyIter_Next(iter);
        ...
        res = NULL;
        do {
            res = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(self, _PyIO_str_write, line, NULL);
        } while (res == NULL && _PyIO_trap_eintr());
        Py_DECREF(line);
        if (res == NULL) {
            Py_DECREF(iter);
            return NULL;
        }
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }
    Py_DECREF(iter);
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

If you notice, there is **no return value!** It simply has `Py_RETURN_NONE` instead of another function call to calculate the size of the written value.

So, I went ahead and tested that there really wasn't a return value.

```
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as f:
    x = f.writelines(["hello", "hello"])
    print(x)

>>> None
```

The extra time that `write` takes seems to be due to the extra function call taken in the implementation to produce the return value. By using `writelines`, you skip that step and the fileio is the only bottleneck.

Edit: [`write` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write)

Comment: How exactly does returning length of string make such a difference? I mean, if you run a regular `return len(line)` it is instantaneous!

Comment: It seems instantaneous, but compounded thousands of times, it might take a while. Also, returning the length uses more memory.

Comment: The order of `len()` is O(1) so i don't think that makes any problem here!

Comment: I realize that its O(1) but that doesn't mean that that calculation can not be a source of the slowdown. O(1) means it is computed in linear time. It still takes time to compute!

Comment: Would it be a good idea to test the write source code with and without the line length calculations?

Comment: Also, the answer below found out that `writelines` also joins all the lines. Maybe putting this in your answer will make it more complete?

Comment: Unaccepted because I don't think there is one answer I can completely accept; there are so many explanations!!

Comment: No offense against you @Brobin

Comment: None taken. It really could be a combination of all of these reasons; the implementation, your computer specs and other factors all go into the speed of a function execution.

Comment: Well, computer specs or not I think that `write` will always take some marginally greater number of time units no matter what the file size is (of course, eventually calculations will be difficult but you can always copy paste a file to itself a zillion times to make it bigger).

Comment: My computer then was a Dell school computer.........average for a school computer which means only slightly horrible

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with the other answer here.

It is simply a coincidence. It highly depends on your environment:

- What OS?
- What HDD/CPU?
- What HDD file system format?
- How busy is your CPU/HDD?
- What Python version?

Both pieces of code do the absolute same thing with tiny differences in performance.

For me personally `.writelines()` takes longer to execute then your first example using `.write()`. Tested with 110MB text file.

*I will not post my machine specs on purpose.*

> Test .write(): ------copying took 0.934000015259 seconds (dashes for readability)
>
> Test .writelines(): copying took 0.936999797821 seconds

Also tested with small and as large as 1.5GB files with the same results. (writelines always beeing slightly slower, up to **0.5sec** difference for **1.5GB file**).

Comment: Maybe if you use longer lines this will take more time

Comment: I think the number of lines makes a difference as well. And if you have a heavenly processor, well, obviously you are getting results :)

Comment: Last thing you could do is change the number of lines collected to `1000000` or something

Comment: I've made a number of different test including short/long lines. My whole point was it is very environment specific rather than python implementation (algorithm) specific.

Answer (score -1):

That's because of that in first part you have to call the method `write` for all the lines in each iteration which makes your program take much time to run. But in second code although your waste more memory but it performs better because you have called the `writelines()` method each 100000 line.

Let see this is source,this is the source of `writelines` function :

```
def writelines(self, list_of_data):
    """Write a list (or any iterable) of data bytes to the transport.

    The default implementation concatenates the arguments and
    calls write() on the result.
    """
    if not _PY34:
        # In Python 3.3, bytes.join() doesn't handle memoryview.
        list_of_data = (
            bytes(data) if isinstance(data, memoryview) else data
            for data in list_of_data)
    self.write(b''.join(list_of_data))
```

As you can see it joins all the list items and calls the `write` function  one time.

Note that joining the data here takes time but its less than the time for calling the `write` function for each line.But since you use python 3.4 in ,it writes the lines one at a time rather than joining them so it would be much faster than `write` in this case :

> - `cStringIO.writelines()` now accepts any iterable argument and writes
>     the lines one at a time rather than joining them and writing once.
>     Made a parallel change to `StringIO.writelines()`.  Saves memory and
>     makes suitable for use with generator expressions.

Comment: Yes, that's what the code is doing, but you didn't expain why the second method is faster.

Comment: But surely `writelines` does more work than `write` would, so you can't just say "it's better to use the approach that has fewer function calls"

Comment: @Brobin Yes I'm looking for the reason in source!

Comment: @Kevin Indeed I would update the answer with that reason!

Comment: So is the time taken up by opening the file and closing it multiple times? And this does not occur with smaller files because you don't open and close as much?

Comment: @ytpillai No, you just open and close the file once! and for smaller files it takes lower time because it calls the `write` function for lower lines and its negligible against joining them.

Comment: @ytpillai Note that since you are using python 3.4 `writelines` performs much better than in python 2.

Comment: So what exactly is the action while writing to the file which maked `write` work much slower?

Comment: @ytpillai Did you read the answer I said `writelines` call the `write` function only once since in second code you have run the `write` multiple time! just this but in  `writelines` you have to join the lines which in python 3 writes the lines one at a time rather than joining them and writing once.